# Declaring javascript variables

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope

What's the difference between the two following ways of declaring javascript variables?

**Version 1**

```
var shadowBox = $(this);
var startInfo = shadowBox.children('.start-info');
var originalHeight = startInfo.height();
```

**Version 2**

```
var shadowBox = $(this),
    startInfo = shadowBox.children('.start-info'),
    originalHeight = startInfo.height();
```

I only ask this because I used the second version within a jquery plugin :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.setUpShadowBox = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({
            boxSpeed: 750,
            boxWidth: 998,
            boxPosition: -40,
            heightSpeed: 500,
            scrollSpeed: 750
        }, options);

        return $(this).each(function () {
            var shadowBox = $(this),
                startInfo = shadowBox.children('.start-info'),
                originalHeight = startInfo.height();

            //rest of plugin code
        });
    };
});
```

but when I used it on a class selector so it had to loop through more than once, it was treating the variables as if they were global and only using the last `originalHeight` that was set.  Once I changed this to the first version of declaring variables, my plugin worked as expected and the variables stayed within their scope.

Why is this?

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of: `var shadowBox = $(this)`

Comment: Actually, this was answered last year and if you look at the comments below the accepted answer, I had not changed a semi colon to a comma.  Not sure where you got your answer from as the code I have shown in the question has the comma - unless you just copied the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you miss the comma on the first line?

If you do this:

```
var shadowBox = $(this)
    startInfo = innerContainer.children('.start-info');
```

Instead of this:

```
var shadowBox = $(this),
    startInfo = innerContainer.children('.start-info');
```

`startInfo` will become a global variable.

Try placing them all on the same line and see what happens.

Comment: For curiousity, why the missing coma make make `startInfo` global?

Comment: Because of automatic semicolon insertion, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Comment: ah, similar mistake - I forgot to change a semi-colon into a comma when I added a new variable! will accept when I can

Comment: So a variable declared like this `function() {var local; global = 2;}`  will be global? Can't see why.

Comment: Learned something one the way! The deeper I go in JS, the more wierd things I found.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Declaring javascript variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929191/declaring-javascript-variables), this will be really useful. Your issue is `var shadowBox = $(this)`, you are missing a comma there.